# How to use SignedRoute on example of unique register URL

Tags: laravel

I created unique url registration, when someone uses link, he will be able to register to my app.

The only problem is, my signed route is invalid and gives 0 on hasValudSignature, where might be the problem?

My register function in RegisterController:

```
public function register(Request $request) {
        abort_unless($request->hasValidSignature(), 403, 'That link has expired or is no longer valid!');

        //they can register now
      }
```

My URL generator:

```
$url = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
                'register',
                now()->addDays(7)
              );
```

After using my user index view it is displayed on page so I can copy link for new user. However when I try to register using this link, at the end I've got information about wrong Validation (error I made by myself to prevent from registering unauthorized people)

Is my `$url` written wrongly?

**Edit**

For some reason after typing in console php artisan route:list

I've got error that

```
ReflectionException::("Class "UserController" does not exist")
```

How might this be possible?

**Edit**

After remakeing controller, I'm back to the original problem with hasValidSignature

Comment: have you tried using the link in an ingognito browser page since the signed link must have the user not logged in to work ?

Comment: Yes, Even on other web browser with same result